# Tune Up Mongo Query

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongo and was trying to get distinct count of users. The field Id and Status are not individually Indexed columns but there exists a composite index on both the field. My current query is something like this where the match conditions changes depending on the requirements.

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 1000000;
db.getCollection('username').aggregate([
  {$match:
    { Status: "A"
    } },
 {"$group" : {_id:"$Id", count:{$sum:1}}}
 ]);
```

Is there anyway we can optimize this query more or add parallel runs on collection so that we can achieve results faster ?

Regards

Comment: If you want you can use `distinct` query. Here's the link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: Direct distinct would take much longer on a non indexed field

Comment: Well as per mongo doc best way to tune is to create index.. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/

Answer (score 0):

You can tune your aggregation pipelines by passing in an option of `explain=true` in the aggregate method.

```
db.getCollection('username').aggregate([
  {$match: { Status: "A" } },
  {"$group" : {_id:"$Id", count:{$sum:1}}}],
{ explain: true });
```

This will then output the following to work with

```
{
        "stages" : [
                {
                        "$cursor" : {
                                "query" : {
                                        "Status" : "A"
                                },
                                "fields" : {
                                        "Id" : 1,
                                        "_id" : 0
                                },
                                "queryPlanner" : {
                                        "plannerVersion" : 1,
                                        "namespace" : "test.usernames",
                                        "indexFilterSet" : false,
                                        "parsedQuery" : {
                                                "Status" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "A"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "winningPlan" : {
                                                "stage" : "EOF"
                                        },
                                        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$group" : {
                                "_id" : "$Id",
                                "count" : {
                                        "$sum" : {
                                                "$const" : 1
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

So to speed up our query we need a index to help the match part of the pipeline, so let's create a index on `Status`

```
> db.usernames.createIndex({Status:1})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If we now run the explain again we'll get the following results

```
{
        "stages" : [
                {
                        "$cursor" : {
                                "query" : {
                                        "Status" : "A"
                                },
                                "fields" : {
                                        "Id" : 1,
                                        "_id" : 0
                                },
                                "queryPlanner" : {
                                        "plannerVersion" : 1,
                                        "namespace" : "test.usernames",
                                        "indexFilterSet" : false,
                                        "parsedQuery" : {
                                                "Status" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "A"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "winningPlan" : {
                                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "Status" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "Status_1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                                "Status" : [ ]
                                                        },
                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "Status" : [
                                                                        "[\"A\", \"A\"]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$group" : {
                                "_id" : "$Id",
                                "count" : {
                                        "$sum" : {
                                                "$const" : 1
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

We can now see straight away this is using a index.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/

Comment: Thanks Kevin. The problem is I cant go and create the index as I am only consumer from DB . So wanted to check if there is a way to do without creating a new index or is there anyway to utilize the existing composite index.

Comment: Run the explain and see what it says, It should be using the indexes set if it can. (can you send across the indexes that are currently configured? `db.usernames.getIndexes()`).

Comment: Also it's a good idea not to just randomly create indexes, you want to have the lowest amount of indexes satisfying the most amount of queries.

Comment: The index set currently existing is Id_Status .. which contains of ID field and Status field .. Also, explain shows that it is not using index.stages.$cursor.queryPlanner.indexFilterSet : False

Comment: If the index is `{ _id: 1, Status: 1}` it wont be used as you'll need to be querying on both _id and Status.

Comment: So I need to run distinct on 2 columns .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151927/discussion-between-user2854333-and-kevin-smith).